# Install PostgreSQL 9.0.4 on Windows silently

Tags: postgresql, windows-installer

I have previously installed PostgreSQL 8.4 with below command through inno set up file.

> postgresql.exe --mode unattended --unattendedmodeui minimal
>   --superpassword admin@123  --prefix "c:\iview\postgres"  --datadir "c:\iview\postgres\data" --install_plpgsql 1 --create_shortcuts 0 '

Now, I want to install OostgreSQL 9.0.4 through above command but it shows an error:

> option datadir,install_plpgsql  invalid please see the help.

Which option should be passed for PostgreSQL 9.0.4 to install it properly from the command line?

Comment: You may ask this kind of questions on http://DBA.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 5):

Check installer's `--help` switch to get all available options, e.g.:

```
postgresql-9.0.4-1-windows_x64.exe --help
```

As I checked there is no `--install_plpgsql` switch available as in earlier version (`postgresql-8.4.8-1-windows.exe`):

```
 --install_plpgsql  Install pl/pgsql in template1 database?
                                Default: 1
```

However if you want `--install_plpgsql 1`, then you can just skip that switch, because PL/pgSQL language is installed by default:

```
SELECT lanname FROM pg_language WHERE lanname LIKE 'plpgsql';
 lanname
---------
 plpgsql
(1 row)
```